Notification permission toggle is disabled for some apps on Samsung
Device: Samsung a03 Core
Some apps has notifications toggled off and switcher is disabled so I can't even manually  toggle it on.
I'm developing an app (Mapmagic on a screenshot) which also uses notifications and foreground services. When I run debug version signed with debug certificate it's possible to toggle notifications on.
When I try to build release version OS disable the notification permission toggle and it's not possible to turn notifications ON. Same happens when I install app via google play with app signin enabled (meaning google re-sign my app bundle).
I've already tried to reinstalled everything, do factory reset of the entire device etc. Even some google apps has the same restrictions so!
Did someone face the same issues with their apps?


I'm not an expert, but could it be that old Samsungs have some additional manifest where you need to declare that the app will be asking for this permissions?

Finally I've managed to find that the issue appears in case of updated target/compile SDK verison and POST_NOTIFICATION permission.
In case you use up-to-date target/compile SDK (starting from android13) you need to declare
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
